# Relationship between the vectors

Tags: vectors

I have the following equations-

$\textbf{a}.\textbf{b}=0$

$\textbf{a}.\textbf{c}=0$

where $\textbf{a},\textbf{b}$ and $\textbf{c}$ are vectors. What are the possible relationships between $\textbf{b}$ and $\textbf{c}$?

I can think of the following three-

1. $\textbf{b}$ and $\textbf{c}$ are parallel
2. $\textbf{b}$ and $\textbf{c}$ are perpendicular (which is true in case of the basis vectors in 3D) and
3. $\textbf{a}$ is a zero vector.
4. $\textbf{b}$ and $\textbf{c}$ are vectors that are linear combinations of vectors given in 1 or 2 (this statement might need correction).

Are there any other possible relationships between the $\textbf{b}$ and $\textbf{c}$

Comment: In which space are you working?

Comment: I had standard 3D vectors in mind. But I would appreciate general answers

Comment: How about $\mathbf a=\mathbf i, \mathbf b=\mathbf j, $ and $\mathbf c=\mathbf j+\mathbf k$?

Comment: Yes, I missed that. What would you say is the general relationship between $\textbf{b}$ and $\textbf{c}$ that applies to the one in your comment, @J.W.Tanner?

Comment: it's none of the above

Comment: Would you say the 4th point I have added applies to the example you gave?

Answer (score 1):

$\vec a. \vec b=0=\vec a. \vec c \implies \vec a =k(\vec b \times \vec c).$

Answer (score 0):

Just some notes:

The inner product of two vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, such as $\vec{c} = \{c_1, \cdots , c_n \}$ e $\vec{b} = \{b_1, \cdots  , b_n \}$, we have

$$\{(c_1,c_2,\cdots, c_n ): c_i \in \mathbb{R}, \forall i = 1, 2, 3, \cdots, n \}$$
$$\{(b_1,b_2,\cdots, b_n ): b_i \in \mathbb{R}, \forall i = 1, 2, 3, \cdots, n \}$$

So,
$$\vec{c}\cdot \vec{b} = c_1 b_1 + c_2 c_2 + \cdots + c_n c_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i b_i  $$

Assuming the space $E^3$ we have $n = 3$

$$\vec{c} \cdot \vec{b} = c_1 b_1 + c_2 b_2 + c_3 b_3$$

Note: For vectors $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}$ I'm using the orthonormal basis $(\vec{i}, \vec{j}, \vec{k})$

It seems that you are giving some assumptions based on
$$\text{If } \vec{a} \perp \vec{b} \text{ and }  \vec{a} \perp \vec{c}, \text{ so } \vec{b} \perp \vec{c}    $$
But the statement above is not true. Consider the vectors as
$\vec{a} = (-5, 1, 1)$, $\vec{b} = (1, 2, 3)$, $\vec{c} = (2, 5, 5)$ and you will see the problem.

For
$\vec{c}\perp \vec{b} \Leftrightarrow \vec{c}\cdot \vec{b} = 0$. So, $\cos(\theta) = \dfrac{\vec{c}\cdot \vec{b}}{\Vert\vec{c}\Vert  \Vert\vec{b}\Vert}=0 \Leftrightarrow \theta = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$

But note that in the dot product you cannot cancel $\vec{a}$

$$\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = \vec{a} \cdot \vec{c} \Leftrightarrow  \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} - \vec{a} \cdot \vec{c} = 0 \Leftrightarrow  \vec{a}(\vec{b} - \vec{c}) = 0 \Leftrightarrow  \vec{a} \perp (\vec{b} - \vec{c})   $$